# Print double number System.out.printf in Java

Tags: java

I have a double number and i want to print only the integral part of this number. I was trying to print it using `System.out.printf` but i i got an `IllegalFormatConversionException`. I tried something like:

```
A()
{ 
    double x;
    //calculate double
    System.out.println("%d",x);
}
```

I know that i can simply print it using `System.out.print` but that will print the decimal part too. How can i do this using `printf`?

Answer (score 15):

```
System.out.printf("%.0f",x);
```

- The **.0** specifies the precision. Number is rounded off according to the precision specified here. (e.g. if you want 2 decimal places you would specify 0.2)
- The **f** specifies it's a floating point - including doubles (d is for decimal integer)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `%g` as well to `round-off` and print double as integer:

```
System.out.printf("x=%g%n", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow code :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = 0 ;//The local variable x must be initialized
    System.out.printf("%d",(int)x);//in JDK 5
           //OR
    System.out.printf("%.0f",x);//in JDK 5
           //OR
    System.out.println((int)x);

}
```